# There are infinite numbers k such that $r(k) = r(k-1)$ where $r(k) = \sum_{i=1}^n n \bmod i$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am working on the following problem:

> There are infinite numbers k such that $r(k) = r(k-1)$ where $r(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n n \bmod i$

NOTE: I have already seen this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660829/sum-of-the-remainder-from-1-to-n).

Much like the above-mentioned question, I started the same way:
Let $f(n,k)$ denotes remainder $n$ divided by $k$, i.e., $n \bmod k$. Then it's easy to see that if $k\mid n$, $f(n,k)+k-1=f(n-1,k)$ and else, $f(n,k)=1+f(n-1,k)$. Then the condition becomes for $q<k$, $\sum_{i=1}^{k}f(k,i)=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}f(k-1,i)=\sum_{q\nmid k}f(k-1,q)+\sum_{q\mid k}f(k-1,q)=\sum_{q\nmid k}(f(k,q)-1)+\sum_{q\mid k}(f(k,q)+q-1)$.

Since I did not know how to proceed, I looked it up and arrived at the question mentioned. However, I do not understand how this followed:
$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}f(k,i)+\sum_{q\mid k}q-(n-1)\implies\sum_{q\mid k}q=k-1...(*)$ which is mentioned in the question.

Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: There is no $k$ on the right hand of your definition of $r(k)$.  Did you mean the summand to be $k\pmod i$?  But then, what is $n$?    So maybe you meant $n=k$?  Hard to guess since later on you have both an $n$ and a $k$.

Comment: @lulu, Yes, it was a mistake. I will edit the question.

Comment: A natural place to start would be with examples.  List a bunch of $k$ such that $r(k)=r(k-1)$.  Maybe there's a pattern or two emerges.  Maybe a really, really obvious pattern.

Comment: @lulu I see that it works for  (1,2), (3,4), (7,8) ...., so it works for $2^i$ and $2^i-1$.